# Matching an expression over multiple lines

Tags: python, regex, multiline

I'm working on extracting the pattern `def ([^\s]+)\([^\.]*\)` in Python. However, when I have multiline input, only the first occurrence is obtained. I have specific the `re.MULTILINE` option on my Python regular expression but still to no avail. Lets say I have the following input:

```
def a():
    pass
b()
def b():
    pass
```

My regular expression only extracts the 'a' and doesn't continue and extract 'b'. The code I'm using is:

```
self.function_re = re.compile(r'def (\S+)\([^\.]*\)', re.MULTILINE)
print(self.function_re.findall(self.code))
```

Which outputs `['a']`.

Comment: Do you use `re.search` or `re.findall`?

Comment: Note that you can use `\S` instead of `[^\s]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing your pattern for the parameter list is too greedy, and matches all the way up to the last closing parenthesis in the string. Try using `def (\S+)\([^\.]*?\)` (note the `?` qualifier after the "zero or more" quantifier for your parameter list).

Comment: Yes, I will but I have to wait 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the `\([^\.]*\)` part is greedy, ie. it matches the whole part from the first parenthesis down to the very last one:

```
>>> r = re.compile(r'def ([^\s]+)(\([^\.]*\))')
>>> r.findall(test)
[('a', '():\n        pass\nb()\ndef b()')]
```

If you make it non-greedy by appending the `?` to the star, it should be all fine:

```
>>> r = re.compile(r'def ([^\s]+)\([^\.]*?\)')
>>> r.findall(test)
['a', 'b']
```